# using appcmd to turn off SSL in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, appcmd

Appcmd will turn off SSL in IIS 7.0 following this command line from microsoft:

appcmd set config " Default Web Site "/section: access /sslFlags:None /commit:APPHOST

I am replacing "Default Web Site" with our own.  The command returns with a statement that it succeeded.  However, when looking at the SSL setting in IIS Mgr, it is still enabled, and the web page is also complaining of the security issue.  I can turn it off via IIS Mgr, but for our needs, it needs to be done at the command line.

There doesn't seem to be any other security issue regarding changing the setting that I have found.  I have tried stopping the site, then applying the appcmd above, starting the site, and same issue.

Any suggestions?
Windows Server 2007

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, that will not turn off SSL, that will just tell IIS that it is ok to allow customers not to use SSL, but the SSL endpoint could very well be there.
If your goal is to remove SSL altogether then you need to also remove the binding from the site that points to 443 something like:
appcmd.exe set config sites /-"[name='YourSite'].bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:']" /commit:apphost

Also, be aware that this will still leave the SSL binding in http.sys so you will need to do also a "netsh http del sslcert 'endpoint in here' "

Answer (score 0):

The command you have above (minus it's spacing problems) works perfectly well for me.  i've just tried it on W7 and IIS7.5

> appcmd set config "Default Web Site" /section:access /sslFlags:None /commit:APPHOST

Are you running the command prompt as administrator?